# Is it possible to complete payments by CASH instead of CARD?

Tags: square-connect

I'm trying to create a payment by CASH on Square but I see there's only field `source_id` represents the card information.
So is there any way to charge the order by cash on Square?

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to create cash transactions via our eCommerce APIs (Payments API). You can only create cash transactions using one of our in-person APIs or basic Square POS application.

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation regarding this?  I have a client who is asking me to use the API of another payment processor to pass data to Square via the Square API, to show orders that have already been paid for from another processor.  I don't believe this is possible, but I don't know how to prove it to them.  Thanks.